# My semaphore from semaphore.h only working after CTR-Z fg

Tags: c

I have a program that prepares some configurations in one process and after that reads those configurations in the parent process. To sync them I'm using semaphores from semaphore.h library. But it seems that it's waiting forever in sem_wait even after I sem_post. It works after I do ctrl-z and fg though. Why is that? Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?
My OS is Lubuntu

Semaphore1.h

```
#ifndef _DNSS_H_
#define _DNSS_H_

#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

typedef struct configs
{
    int i;
    sem_t sem;
} CONFIGS;


void init_config(CONFIGS *_configs);
//initiates the threadpool 
int init_thread_pool(CONFIGS *configs);

#endif
```

Semaphore_1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "semaphore1.h"



void init_config(CONFIGS *_configs)
{
    sem_init(&(_configs->sem),1,0); //Creaates a semaphore that is opened  when the configs are read to shared memory

    _configs->i=2;

    fprintf(stderr, "Result of sem_post:%d\n", sem_post(&(_configs->sem)));
}
```

Semaphore_2.c

```
#include"semaphore1.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int init_thread_pool( CONFIGS *configs)
{
    int aux;

    fprintf(stderr, "Value of sem_wait():%d\n", sem_wait(&(configs->sem)));

    printf("Threadpool initiated with %d threads!", configs->i);

    return 1;
}
```

Semaphore_main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include "semaphore1.h"
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t config_pid; //will hold the configuration process id
    int _shmid_configs;
    CONFIGS *_configs;

    _shmid_configs =shmget( IPC_PRIVATE, 
                             sizeof(CONFIGS), IPC_CREAT|0666); //initializes the shared memory

    if( _shmid_configs == -1)
    {
        perror("Error creating shared memory");
    }
    _configs=shmat(_shmid_configs, NULL,0); //maps the shared memory created to the processp and the config structure
    if( _configs == ( CONFIGS*)-1)
    {
        perror("Error at shmat");
    }

    //initialization of the processes
    config_pid = fork();
    if( config_pid < 0)
    {
        perror("Failed creating configuration manager process");
    }
    else if( config_pid == 0)
    {
        init_config(_configs);
        printf("Im config!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //CODE FOR THE gestor de pedidos
    printf("right before the threadpool! Configs has a lmit of %d theads\n", _configs->i);
    init_thread_pool(_configs);
    printf("im parent and im out\n");
    sem_destroy(&_configs->sem);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with
gcc -g -pthread Semaphore_2.c Semaphore_main.c Semaphore_1.c -o deb

Output:

```
./deb
right before the threadpool! Configs has a lmit of 0 theads
Result of sem_post:0
Im config!
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./deb
fg
./deb
Value of sem_wait():0
Threadpool initiated with 2 threads!im parent and im out
```

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Answer (score 1):

`sem_init()` should be called **before** `fork()`.

In your current code it is possible for `init_thread_pool(_configs);` in the parent thread to be called *before* `init_config()`, that is you will wait on uninitialized semaphore. It is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: But the semaphore doesnt return a error though. How can i see the error mentioned in the manual about unitialized senaphores? Thanks anyway!

Comment: While `sem_wait` [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html) tells about `EINVAL` error in case of non-valid semaphore, I think that using non-initialized semaphore is just *undefined behaviour* - it can return error, awake immediately, or wait forever.